# SQL - trigger to delete a row based on a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I would like some advice on completing the following task:

I have three tables:

Table 1 has "all" columns, and tables 2 and 3 have the same subset of columns from table 1.

Table 1 - Col 1, Col 2, Col 3, Col 4, Col 5, Col 6
Table 2 - Col 1, Col 2, Col 5
Table 3 - Col 1, Col 2, Col 5

I have a trigger on Table 1 that when Col 3 = '1' will insert Columns 1,2 and 5 into Table 2 AFTER INSERT.

I have a second trigger on Table 1 that when Col 3 = '10' will insert Columns 1,2 and 5 into Table 3 AFTER INSERT.

This system is tracking serialized parts, so for any one part, column 2 will be the same for each part (serial number).

What I need is, when the trigger that inserts a record to Table 3 occurs, I want to go back to Table 2 and delete any records where Col 2 contains a value equal to the value in col 2 of the INSERT.

This value is a 20 character string, and I cannot find an example of pulling the actual value from a column in an insert to use in a SELECT or DELETE.

Thank you

Comment: Is the value of column 2 dynamic... i.e. you don't know its value until after the insert because it's assigned by something like "newid()" as a column default?  Is that why it's a problem?  Or is the value determined by the application, and thus literally being inserted as a static value?

Comment: Yes, this works in a relatively large manufacturing system, there are around 200 serial numbers in the system at a time.   i won't know what the serial number is when it shows up.  Essentially, I want to record when a part comes into and leaves the area, Col 3 = '1' means that it just entered the area, and Col 3 = '10' means it is leaving.

Comment: But is the value being inserted literally, or is the value sent "NULL" and thus the database server generates the value for you?  In the first case, it's easy, because you know the value in the trigger... in the latter case, it's harder, because you don't.  I'm still not clear on what you mean about how the serial number is populated.  It seems like a part would have a fixed serial number, in which case, it's inserted literally, so there's no problem to solve here... it's in the inserted collection.

Comment: There is a C# application on a PC that generates an INSERT to the SQL database, this INSERT contains string-type data for each column.  Each part has a laser marked serial number on it, and that serial number value is inserted into Column 2 as a string data type.

Comment: I think what I don't know how to do is reference the value out of the column from within the trigger code?  If I was able to obtain the number from the INSERT I would hopefully be able to DELETE from Table 2 where col 2 = 'value of col 2 from insert that generated the trigger'

Comment: the "insert that generated the trigger" is contained in the `inserted` table, which is a virtual table that exists only in the context of a trigger.   Pretty much any web-tutorial about triggers is going to explain what the `inserted` table is and how to use it.

Comment: Are there any issues with implementing Tables 2 & 3 as views instead of trigger-updated tables? If not, that might be the simpler way of achieving your end-results.

Answer (score 1):

You need a trigger for table 1, that inserts the values in table 2 and 3:

```
create trigger insertTrigger1 on dbo.T1
  After Insert
  as
    insert into T2 select col1,col2, col5 From Inserted where col3 = 1
    insert into T3 Select col1,col2, col5 From Inserted where col3 = 10
```

and a trigger for table 3 to delete table 2 records:

```
create trigger insertTrigger3 on dbo.T3
After Insert
  as
    delete from T2 where col2 in(select col2 from Inserted)
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/213c4/1) for it.

Comment: This worked, thanks so much!  I'm not a database guy (machine controls guy), and I appreciate you all helping me out because I was not going to figure this one out.